# how to Iterate over selected elements and get input values

Tags: jquery

I have got an array of elements via jquery selectors but I know the selection contains some href,dropdown with and without multiselect as well as date and time text boxes. Now I want to get values from all of them.

`myArray = $('.'+fName[fName.length-1]+'');`

or I can say

```
myArray = $('.class');
```

Comment: And what is your question? add `.val()`?

Comment: how do you want values as an array or object

Answer (score 3):

To get all the values from an array of inputs, do this:

```
var values = [];
var myArray = $('input'); // Or whatever list of inputs you select for
myArray.each(function(){
  values.push($(this).val());
});

//And now values is an array of all the values of those elements.
```

Comment: can you tell me what all we can get out of this.
apart from 
`$(this).val()`
like can we get name, type and id

Comment: You can get all of that. `$(this).attr('name')` `$(this).attr('type')` `$(this).attr('id')` will give you the name, type, and ID of the input element. You can use that inside the function passed to `.each()`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery object into an array see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/

```
var obj = jQuery("input"); // jQuery object
var arr = jQuery.makeArray(obj); // arraylist
```

jQuery code line:615 http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js

```
// results is for internal usage only
makeArray: function( arr, results ) {
    var ret = results || [];

    if ( arr != null ) {
        if ( isArraylike( Object(arr) ) ) {
            jQuery.merge( ret,
                typeof arr === "string" ?
                [ arr ] : arr
            );
        } else {
            core_push.call( ret, arr );
        }
    }

    return ret;
},
```

so try the code:

```
var get_elements_attr = function(selector, attr_name) {
    var result_list = [];
    jQuery(selector).each(function() {

        result_list.push(jQuery(this).attr(attr_name));
    });
    return result_list;
};

// id attribute
get_elements_attr("input", "id")

// values attribute
get_elements_attr("input", "value")
```

Answer (score 0):

For each of the item in the collection you can get the value using the jQuery api .val() right?